# Project a hierarchical list, to another hierarchical list with anonymous types (or dynamic)?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have a list of **strongly-typed** objects. Say `List<Activity>`. Each `Activity` has many properties, say `Title`, `Id`, `ParentActivity`, `ChildrenActivities`, `ActivityType`, etc. The list is hierarchical, that is, each activity in the list might have children activities, and each child activity might still have its own children activity, and so on.

I need to convert this list into JSON, so that I can use it with a third-party JavaScript UI library. However, the target list has only a subset of properties of the original list, say `Id`, and `Title`.

Because I have many types and many places with the same condition, I don't want to define target list type, thus I don't have a **strongly-typed** target. In other words, I don't have `List<SubActivity>` and I don't want to create the `SubActivity` class.

How can I do this hierarchical conversion on the fly, and then get the JSON string from the target list? Is it possible at all using `dynamic` keyword, **anonymous types**?

**Update:**

Imagine that `Activity` is:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ActivityType Type { get; set; }

    public string ActivityTitle { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Activity? Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Activity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a hierarchical list of this class instances:

```
List<Activity> activities = ActivityManager.GetActivitiesHierarchically();
```

Now, I need to convert this hierarchical list, into a JSON string, but I don't need to render some properties, including `Description` for example. Thus, before serializing the list into JSON, I need to do a **projection** (some kind of conversion). I might create a type named `JsonActivity` which is like:

```
public class JsonActivity
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public List<JsonActivity> items { get; set; }
}
```

But because this pattern is repeated in many places of my code for different types, I don't want to define `JsonEntity` DTOs.

Is there a way to do a hierarchical conversion with projection on the fly?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what exactly do you want, ideally with an example? What do you mean by “many places”? Do you have several hierarchical types similar to `Activity`? Or do you just use `Activity` in several places? What are the differences between those places?

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using?

Comment: I'm using `JavaScriptSerializer` from **.NET Framework**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't create recursive anonymous types in C#, so trying to use them won't work.

But since you're going to serialize the result as a JSON, using `Dictionary<string, object>` instead should work.

The lambda has to be recursive, though. To solve that, you can write a lambda that takes itself as a parameter:

```
delegate IDictionary<string, object> RecursiveSelector<TSource>(
    RecursiveSelector<TSource> selector, TSource source);

static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> RecursiveSelect<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    RecursiveSelector<TSource> selector)
{
    return source.Select(x => selector(selector, x));
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
List<Activity> activities = …;
var result = activities.RecursiveSelect(
    (s, a) =>
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    { 
        { "id", a.Id },
        { "title", a.ActivityTitle },
        { "children", a.Children.Select(c => s(s, c)).ToArray() }
    });
```

Comment: Though this answer was not exactly what I wanted, but it helped me to get my work done. However, it seems that **projection of a strongly-typed hierarchical list to an anonymous hierarchical list** is not possible.

Comment: That's what I said: you can't create recursive anonymous type.